# PHP to use read/write NFC chip

Tags: php, nfc

Am new to NFC and my project demands for the NFC chip to read and write data on it.

I have been working on PHP since long and so was looking if anyone has worked on NFC+PHP.

I have been checking few things for the documentation which are as follows but with the first look its doesn't seems to be inspiring or very helpful.

https://www.w3.org/2012/nfc/web-api/

http://www.nxp.com/

The question has also been posted on NXP community but there seems no help so if anyone have used or worked on.

Link for NXP community https://community.freescale.com/thread/391793

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Did any of the given answers help?

Answer (score 1):

Since php is designed primarily as a server side scripting language there is next to no support for anything hardware specific available. That leaves you with two possible approaches:

1. you can use any available command line utility to interact with hardware by using phps ability to start (execute) sub processes (`system()`, `exec()`, ...). [nfc-tools.org](http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=Related_links) might be a good starting point to find a suitable utility for your setup.
2. you can implement a php extension for that purpose, so a library that can be loaded into php. That way you can offer a native solution inside the php language itself, so you don't have to rely on expensive and risky sub process execution. However this is not a trivial task. [php-cpp](http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-php-extension-development-via-php-cpp/) on github might be a place to start learning about that. Plus you probably want to look for an existing and usable nfc library implemented in c / c++ that you can modify for your means.

This all is not exactly straight forward. So maybe you should question your selection of the php language for this task in the first place. There certainly are languages around that are much better suited for your task.

Answer (score 0):

NFC chips normally are used in smartphones, so I think you must use a language running on the smartphone to access it. PHP, on the other hand, is a language normally used on a web server and not on a smartphone.

It's possible to use a language like Java on Android smartphones or Swift on iOS to access NFC and then send data to the server and use PHP to work with the information.

There is also a Cordova plugin available (https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc) which makes it possible to use JavaScript on the smartphone side, so that you get a platform independent solution.